# Hamming(7,4) problem : Check my answer is correct or incorrect.

Tags: coding-theory

Find a data to be transmitted with Hamming(7,4) if given data bits : 1010.

$a_1=a_3\oplus a_5\oplus a_7=1\oplus0\oplus0=1$

$a_2=a_3\oplus a_6\oplus a_7=1\oplus1\oplus0=0$

$a_3=a_5\oplus a_6\oplus a_7=0\oplus1\oplus0=1$

\begin{eqnarray}
a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4&a_5&a_6&a_7\\
1&0&1&1&0&1&0
\end{eqnarray}

Is it correct answer?

Comment: Depends on the concrete generator matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it all depends on the generator matrix, say
$$G =\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right).$$
Then $(a,b,c) G = (a,b,c,d,a+c+d,a+b+c,a+b+c)$, in particular $(1,0,1,0)G =(1,0,1,0,0,1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Wuestenfux